# SVG Viewbox and display size best practises

Tags: html, svg

I've noticed this on chrome while debugging an img tag with and svg file.

[image: Svg image size]

Although SVG is meant to be scalable and the all scaling is done correctly. There is an initial size to the "image" defined by viewbox attribute.

Should we always try to aim for the viewbox to be the same as the display size? Or is this something not really relevant to both SEO and the rendering time of the page on the browser?

Answer (score 1):

The viewbox is the logical part of your SVG that defines how the coordinates within the SVG are interpreted. For example, a viewbox of 0,0,1,1 and a rectangle of 0,0,1,1 are exactly the same as a viewbox of -10,-10,10,10 and a rectangle of that dimension.

This has nothing to do with the output size which can (and must) be defined on the tag itself or via css.

If you double the size of your viewbox, your entire image gets shrunken by half because you double the "viewing window" internally while the coordinates of your elements stay the same. Imagine that as "zooming out".